# Rails routes /new(.:format)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have a wordsController, I understand that

```
GET    /words(.:format)          /words#index
```

this route has a (.:format) at the end of the route so that I can choose different response format.

```
GET    /words/new(.:format)      /words#new
```

Why is there a (.:format) for the new action ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not about querying words with conditions, it's about providing different formats for Rails to respond to.  See the period?  That's so you can do things like: `/words.json` and get a JSON response, or `/words.csv` and get a CSV response.

You're right that there's no reason to have a `/words/new.json` URL, but Rails just adds the `(.:format)` to all URLs just in case you need/want it for some format.